# Calculating a certain definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate the following :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{ax}}-\frac{1}{1+e^{bx}}\text{ }\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\tag{a}
\int \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{ax}} dx &= \frac{1}{a} \int \frac{1}{u(u-1)} du \\
\tag{b}
&= \frac{1}{a} \int \left(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u}\right) du \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \Big[\mathrm{ln}(u-1) - \mathrm{ln}(u) \Big] \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \Big[ax - \mathrm{ln}(1+\mathrm{e}^{ax}) \Big]
\end{align}

Applying the limits of integration we obtain
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{ax}} dx = \frac{1}{a} \mathrm{ln}(2)$$

Thus we have
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{ax}} - \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{bx}}
= \left(\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b}\right) \mathrm{ln}(2)
\end{equation}

a. $u=1+\mathrm{e}^{ax}$

b. partial fractions

Answer (score 0):

*Suggestion:* split the integral into a difference of two integrals. Multiply through the denominator and numerator of the first integrand with $ e^{-ax}$, and do the equivalent for the second integral. At that point, think substitution. Is that enough?

Comment: Do you need more details?

Answer (score 0):

The integral has a closed form for $a>0$:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+e^{a x}}dx=\frac{\ln 2}{a}$$